# Permission denied on checking java version in ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, intellij-idea, sbt

On asking java -version -

```
  java -version

  bash: /home/user/jdk-8u221-linux-x64/jdk1.8.0_221/bin/java: Permission denied
```

it says permission denied , but on using sudo it gives.
Due to which intelliJ is also not able to build project .
How to get access or how do I provide priveleg to the user

also showing problem in intellij -

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this command

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/java
```